# Update Daedalus Cardano CLI version?

Tags: cardano-cli, daedalus

I'm currently using the cardano-cli that comes with Daedalus, which according to `cardano-cli --version` is `v1.30.1`

Is there any way to update the CLI? I'm trying to access the `--required-signer` flag which I don't believe was released until the latest alpha version.

Comment: To answer my own question, you can build your own version of `cardano-cli` by cloning the `cardano-node` Github repo and running a nix-shell, then `cabal build cardano-cli`. Although I'm not sure how to access this cli outside of the nix-shell.

Answer (score 0):

1.30.1 is the latest version of the cli.  If you're trying to add a required signer, you might want to look at the `transaction sign` operation on the cardano-cli.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've worked through this issue.

For anyone else that finds themselves here:
You can download the binaries (Win/Lin/Mac) or make from source.
Details for each approach are on the github repo https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node